# Passing instance variable to selector configured in CCMenuItemImage

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I need a hand passing a variable to a selector configured in a CCMenuItemImage, if that's even possible.  Seems like it should be, I just can't work it out!

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Create menu of say 20 game levels items with
   for/loop.  No problem.
2. In the for/loop, specify
   incrementing variable. No problem.
3. Pass incrementing variable to selector specified in
   CCMenuItemImage. Problem!
4. Use incrementing variable to
   determine what game level to load when particular menu item is tapped. Problem without #3 solved!

Anyway, on with the (cut down for clarity) code:

Here's the command used within the for/loop to create the menu item

```
CCMenuItemImage *image = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"Normal.png" selectedImage:@"Selected.png" target:self selector:@selector(onSelect:)];
```

Now as you can see in the above snippet, there's no space for say 'userinfo' like the NSTimer class provides for this very purpose.

Ideally, instead of pointing each CCMenuItemImage to the same selector which I can't pass a variable to, I'd actually prefer to call a method like this one below.  The int would represent the game level that should be loaded when the CCMenuItemImage is tapped:

```
- (void)onSelectWithStage:(int)selectedStage {

// write the selected stage to the GameData.xml

    [SceneManager goLevelSelect];
}
```

Anyway I think that pretty much sums up the issue.  Hopefully I'm missing something glaringly obvious :)

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use tags!

```
for(int i = 0;i<MAX_LEVELS;i++)
{
    CCMenuItemImage *image = [CCMenuItemImage 
                                       itemFromNormalImage:@"Normal.png"
                                             selectedImage:@"Selected.png" 
                                                    target:self   
                                                  selector:@selector(onSelect:)];
    image.tag = i;
}
```

And adjust your onSelect method accordingly.

```
-(void)onSelect:(CCMenuItemImage*)item{
    int lvl = item.tag;
    [self onSelectWithStage:lvl]; 
}
```

Comment: +1 Using tag is the simplest and recommended way to do it: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/66206-cocos2d-ccmenuitem-check-button-touched.html

Answer (score 1):

The approach I would take is to add the levels to an NSDictionary keyed on a CCMenuItemImage instance, so create the level, create the menu item and add the level to the dictionary keyed on its menu item.

When the selector fires, you are given a reference to the CCMenuItemImage that sent it, simply get the level from the dictionary with the key that matches the menu item.

Simples.